# Reference to another repository

Tags: git, github

How can I in a repo, say `master-repo`, have a *file* or more like entry to another repository?

For a specific example, take [Redox OS's GitHub](https://github.com/redox-os/redox) repo. Notice there's both `installer`, `libc` and `rust` entries in there, which are similar to symlinks to a different repo (in this case, a mirror of another repo).

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called submodules.

[The Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and [the documentation for the `git submodule` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) have more information.